# Handle updating documents at the same time in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Let's say I have a document in CouchDB and two users access that document to edit that at the same time.

How can I handle that because if the document is updated the _rev number will be changed and the other user could not save his changes..

How to merge both updates users made over the same documents?

Answer (score 0):

You either resolve this client side sending update again with fresh `_rev` or (better) write the [update handler function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers). Update handler takes as the argument current (up to date) document and parameters delivered from the user who executes the update. As the result function should return new document or null. You can considered it as server-side update in place. This way you do not have to worry about the `_ver` field.

Comment: I don't understand how this Update Handler Function works.. Can you explain in details?

Comment: Update handler is a function in the design document (same as map function). When you go to the URL `/DB_NAME/_design/DESIGN_NAME/_update/FUN_NAME/DOC_ID` it is executed. Couch passes current document and request data (including additional parameters in URL and the body) as the arguments to the function. Return value is the pair: new document and the response to the user who executed the URL. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#update-functions) and the examples in [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers).

Comment: where should be written this function?

Comment: In the same place where other [design function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html) are - in design document. Take a look at the introductory description in [The Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/design.html). The view with design document is the very basic idea behind the CouchDB and you should understand it before going any further with this system.

Comment: I'm using views to get information about the documents or to get some of the documents by ID, but I don't understand where to store this function. The Url of the views is: _design/{design_name}/_view/{view_name}. How to make _update ?

Comment: As explained (with the examples) in already cited [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers), you should add filed `updates` in your design document with the update functions: `{... updates: {"my_updt_fn": "function (doc,rec){...}, "other_updt_fn": ... } ...}`